# How to make log file as a zip file?

Tags: java, logback

I have an application, in which I use logback. My logback.xml file is like so  :

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>myApp.log</file>

    <encoder>
      <Pattern>%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", UTC} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} %L - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <Pattern>%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", UTC} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} %L - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="source.main.FileProcess" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="source.main.FileReadWrite" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="source.main.OperatorLoader" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="source.exception.ValidationException" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="source.validation.Validation" level="INFO" />
 <logger name="source.main.OperatorLoader" level="DEBUG" />

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Now I want to say if my myApp.log file's size become 100 KB then convert it to a  zip the myApp.log  .
Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like below, this is what I use in our project.  It creates folder for the month, and keeps daily file in it in `gz` format

```
<timestamp key="date" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
   <file>myApp.log</file>
   <append>true</append>
   <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>archived_logs_%d{yyyy-MM,aux}/myApp_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
   </rollingPolicy>
   <maxHistory>180</maxHistory>
   <encoder>
      <pattern>[%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%t] [%p] [%logger{5}] [%X] %msg%n</pattern>
   </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you read [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html), there is a section stating that `FixedWindowRollingPolicy`, `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` appenders will compress the log file if the name specified ends with `.zip` or `.gz`

> Just like FixedWindowRollingPolicy, TimeBasedRollingPolicy supports
>   automatic file compression. This feature is enabled if the value of
>   the fileNamePattern option ends with .gz or .zip.

I guess it will something like

```
<file>test.log</file>

<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
  <fileNamePattern>tests.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
  <minIndex>1</minIndex>
  <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
</rollingPolicy>
```

Comment: She is concerned about the size and `FixedWindowRollingPolicy` will not  help in that case

Comment: no, but the accepted answer is essentially the same thing.